# Why does Python require the following to be a global name?

Tags: python, csv

```
for i in range(len(rec)):
   temp[i] = rec[i]
   i = i + 1
return temp
```

I am trying to parse a CSV file. This function breaks 1 line into into it's individual words and then stores them into an array.  I thought Python's variable type definitions are automatic.  Why is it giving me this error?

```
Name Error: global name 'temp' is not defined.
```

I never used the global keyword throughout my code at all.

Comment: It depends on how you wrote the rest of your code. Where did you define temp?

Comment: did you define `temp` before entering this loop??

Comment: I did not define temp before entering the loop.  So defining an array within a loop in python is unacceptable?

Comment: But you're *not* defining it within the loop! You're *referencing* it, and trying to assign one of its indexes, but you haven't defined it anywhere.

Comment: I see.  So how do I define an empty array where the length is unknown length in python.  I tried temp= [] and temp = list() but I get a index out of range error.

Comment: use the `append` method.

Comment: Disregard I have to APPEND to the list, my apologies noob mistake.

Comment: read [this](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html).

Comment: yeah, next time read a bit about the language before posting . . . :)

Answer (score 2):

You've misunderstood what lists are in Python. They are not fixed-length arrays. What you want to do is take an empty list, and append to it:

```
temp = []
for elem in rec:
   temp.append(elem)
```

Also note that it's much more Pythonic to iterate through a thing - ie `rec` - directly, rather than keeping an index.